# Really simple Django deployment for low-traffic intranet use

Tags: django

I'm designing a Django system. Traffic will be very low (1 user on the admin interface, maybe 4 requests a minute on a small db), so I'm not really worried about performance. It will be deployed on many servers, so I want to make it as easy as possible to set up.

My initial thought was to serve everything (dynamic and static) using a Gunicorn server.

However, the standard advice is that it's important to serve static and media files using a specialised web server. In fact, Django itself makes it difficult to serve these when `DEBUG = True`, take for example `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve`:

```
def serve(request, path, document_root=None, insecure=False, **kwargs):
    """
    Serve static files below a given point in the directory structure or
    from locations inferred from the staticfiles finders.

    To use, put a URL pattern such as::

        (r'^(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve')

    in your URLconf.

    It uses the django.views.static view to serve the found files.
    """
    if not settings.DEBUG and not insecure:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("The staticfiles view can only be used in "
                                   "debug mode or if the --insecure "
                                   "option of 'runserver' is used")
```

The use of the word 'insecure' got me thinking... is this just a performance concern? Should I really set up two servers, or would one be sufficient in my case?

Comment: It is the protocol - `https` is `secure` and `http` is `insecure`. That is standard terminology

Comment: Ah, I see. I might change the question a little bit then!

Comment: Actually, checking [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view) for this view, they mention that it's insecure here too.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to run something like nginx and then use uwsgi (or I guess Gunicorn) to serve the django site. You'll only have to set this up once, and then your application will scale nicely. Setting up nginx is quick and and easy, and there are a good number of tutorials around.